# branched cover over slice disk is a rational ball

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, 4-manifolds

Can you help me find a proof of the fact that the double branched cover over a slice disc is a rational homology ball?

There is an identical question on stackexchange, but I looked at the answer and it seems to me it relies on the fact that on the boundary, the double branched cover over a slice knot is a rational homology sphere, which is not clear to me either.

Comment: Could you link to the other question?

Comment: See lemma 4.2 in https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjvtI-Sy82EAxWZhK8BHQZeB_AQFnoECBgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.ed.ac.uk%2F~v1ranick%2Fpapers%2Fcassgord1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3K6RKNCpN9D0jFBRbTmGTi&opi=89978449